# T-note returns from T-note yields ... derivation of Damodaran's formula

Tags: fixed-income, returns

Damodaran's historical data on 10-year T-note returns ([found here](http://www.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/pc/datasets/histretSP.xls)) uses the following formula to calculate the 1-period total return on a T-note ($R_1$) given the 10-year constant maturity yield-to-maturity in the prior year ($Y_0$) and the current year ($Y_1$).

$R_1=(Y_0*\frac{1-(1+Y_1)^{-10}}{Y_1}+\frac{1}{(1+Y_1)^{10}})-1+Y_0$

Where can I find a derivation or description of this formula? It seems very odd to me that the only two data points I would need to calculate the total return to a T-note are the beginning and ending yield-to-maturities.

Comment: Not sure how accurate that formula is, but over short intervals all you really need is the current yield and the previous period's yield.

Comment: I get that you can do that for a given instrument, but the index isn't a given instrument. So you have to make assumptions about what year 11 looks like, etc.

Comment: I think the assumption is that the index is continually rebalanced into a hypothetical 10-year security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First term in parens is the annuity formula applied to a 10 year stream of coupon payments at rate y0, second term in parens is discounted one dollar of principal payable at ten year maturity.  Then subtract $1 invested today and add a current cash coupon at rate y0.

Comment: Silly question, but why wouldn't I look at a 9-year annuity (i.e. the original 10-year annuity less the 1 year of cash flow from year 1)?

Comment: I have the same question, why is it still 10-year cash flow when you sell the bond at the end of the first year? Shouldn't it be 9 year remaining?